# how capture second or multiple mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener

how to identify or listen a second mouse wheel with DOM events.

```js
document.addEventListener( 'wheel', ( e ) => {
    const delta = e.deltaY > 0 ? 0.1 : -0.1;
    const old = $Camera.data._zoom;
    let zoom = old + delta;
    zoom = Math.min( Math.max( zoom, 0.1 ), 4 );

if('weel2') 'stuff...'; // what the hack for this ?


} );
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you are just looking for the `event.deltaX` to get horizontal scroll value? There is no interface for identifying specific mouse wheels or telling them apart.

Comment: what about if the shift key is pressed? when shift is pressed, `deltaY` gets converted to `deltaX` so it is indistinguishable from a side scroll. i'd like to be able to differentiate between side wheel plus shift and normal wheel plus shift